# how can i insert data into MS Access from Sqlserver 2008 database table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2007

I am using this query for insert data into MS Access from Sql server 2008 database using C#

```
 INSERT INTO
 Table1([sno],[DataOfCreation],[Time],[IdentityType],[Description],[SpenderName],[Amount],[VoucherNo],[Session],[Mid],[Type])select
 [sno],[DataOfCreation],[Time],[IdentityType],[Description],[SpenderName],[Amount],[VoucherNo],[Session],[Mid],[Type]
 from
 [OLEDB;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=CMACHINE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Voucher;].Voucher_Details";
```

But I found an **Error** :

```
"Could not found installable ISAM" .
```

Can Anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: check this link. http://www.packtpub.com/article/transferring-data-ms-access-2003-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: you can also check this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUDQT4zdXE0

Answer (score 1):

ISAM drivers are used by Access to update file formats other than its own. If the path of the ISAM driver in your Windows Registry is not valid, or if the ISAM driver does not exist, the problem may occur.

This error will also be generated when the syntax of the connection string is incorrect. This commonly occurs when using multiple Extended Properties parameters. Below is an example:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=e:\DB.mdb;Extended Properties=""Access 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
```

See your datasource is quoted or not. This must be a problem in connection string.

Comment: I want to data from sqlserver 2008 tables for insert data into mS Access so please help me for connection string SqlServer 2008 database using C#

Comment: @Swati you can fill in values for connection string as i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: Hello sir you send me connection string for MS Access but I want for Sql Server

Comment: Server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;Database=DBNAME;integrated security=true

Comment: thanks for give me resonse I am using "[OLEDB;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=CMACHINE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Voucher;integrated security = true;" but again I found same error "Could not installable ISAM"